# How to search a value from multiple XML file Using Windows Application

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have multiple XML file in one folder from which I want to search one value. After Searching the value I want to move those file in which that searched value found into other folder.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Read XML one by one
        // Move the all the file in which search value match
        //folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Someone please help me.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: I am not getting how to read multiple file, stuck at the starting it self

Comment: Start by writing code to read a single file. Then add a loop around it to execute it once for each filename.

Comment: xmlsh (http://www.xmlsh.org) is good at this kind of thing, so is Ant. Though I would write an XSLT 2.0 script, not because it's the best tool for the job, but because it's the tool I know best.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you generally do it (untested);

```
string directory = "C:/Folder";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
string[] xmls = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.xml");
for (int i = 0; i < xmls.Length; i++)
{
     xml.Load(xmls[i]);
     XmlNode node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("node");
     if (node.InnerText == "WHAT_YOU_ARE_SEARCHING_FOR")
     {
          // Your action
     }
}
```